# Recovering a zip decryption password I have used it once and then forgot it

Tags: windows, encryption, passwords, zip

So I have received a ZIP file that is password encrypted.

I have used [BreeZip](https://www.breezip.com/) to unzip and view the files initially, which required a password, which I have lost. As I was using the free version of BreeZip, the remember password feature does not work.

I have tried various decryption tools and checked the machine's saved passwords, but nothing works.

If I try to open/unzip with Windows Explorer, I get this:

[image: Windows error message]

When I get to the folder, I can even see the image names, but I get this:

[image: windows error message2]

And BreeZip greets me with this:

[image: BreeZip]

I had the files open once via BreeZip, but accidentally closed the program and could never access the files since.

Shouldn't these files be somewhere if the zip folder had been unzipped and the files opened? If yes, where can I find them?

If I go to AppData, even after restoring some from the bin, I get this:

[image: APPDATA]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ive never used breezip, but you know the file names.  Why not do a global search for some of them to see if they exist in an alternative location (ie you decompressed them somewhere).  If you dont have a copy of the files,  dont know the password and cant get it elsewhere, your only alternative is to try a brute force atteck - there are cloud services that can assist - ofcourse its not guaranteed.

Comment: ZIP format includes the names of things inside of the archive without a password.  No, there is not a temp copy somewhere.  As @davidgo points out, you will need a zip file password cracker.  It could take between now and when we are all dead to come up with the actual password but is worth trying.  Google "zip file password cracker" and see what suits you.

Comment: I tried a brute force, but got loads of errors, however, I just googled the first best ones, do you have a solid suggestion on one that works?

Comment: Different encryption schemes are in use. 7-Zip, for example, gives a choice of Zip-Crypto and AES-256. That further complicates "cracking" the file.

Comment: When brute forcing you will get a lot of errors because only 1 password actually works and the rest will fail.  It is likely you will have billions of failure before it succeeds.  Thus depending on the length of your password it could take days,months, or years to crack it.